# How does BigDecimal.toDouble Work?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I am using BigDecimal and doubles in my math program. What decimal places does this method take? Is it fast? Is this recommended over just using BigDecimal?

Comment: What does the JavaDoc say? Which problems are you facing? And btw which `BigDecimal` class are you referring to? `java.math.BigDecimal` doesn't have a `toDouble()` - at least not in the version of Java 8 I currently have access to. Or do you mean `doubleValue()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How does BigDecimal.toDouble work?

Multiplications and additions.  Take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/math/BigDecimal.java).  (You can find it by googling for "java.math.BigDecimal source".)

> Q: What decimal places does this method take?

Here is what the javadoc states:

> *"Converts this BigDecimal to a double. This conversion is similar to the narrowing primitive conversion from double to float as defined in section 5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigDecimal has too great a magnitude represent as a double, it will be converted to Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY or Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY as appropriate."*

5.1.3 of the JLS states:

> *"A narrowing primitive conversion from double to float is governed by the IEEE 754 rounding rules (§4.2.4). This conversion can lose precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a nonzero double and a float infinity from a finite double. A double NaN is converted to a float NaN and a double infinity is converted to the same-signed float infinity."*

And 4.2.4 states:

> *"The Java programming language requires that floating-point arithmetic behave as if every floating-point operator rounded its floating-point result to the result precision. Inexact results must be rounded to the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result; if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero is chosen. This is the IEEE 754 standard's default rounding mode known as round to nearest."*

---

So what does this mean?

1. If the number is representable, the `BigDecimal.doubleValue()` will give the `double` value that is closest to the *Real* number represented by the object.
2. If the number is not representable (i.e. it is too large or too small to be represented as a `double`) then the method will give +INF or -INF.

---

> Q:  Is it fast?

It is typically roughly as fast as converting a string representation of the number to a `double`.  (Indeed, in some cases the conversion is actually done by converting the value to a string and then parsing it!)

Fast is a relative term.

> Q: Is this recommended over just using BigDecimal?

Recommended for what purpose?

If you convert `BigDecimal` values to `double` values, then operations on the `double` values will be orders of magnitude faster than the analogous `BigDecimal` operations.  But the results won't be as accurate.  (Assuming that you specify the `BigDecimal` precision appropriately.)

Comment: Thanks, I am using this for a calculator and I want precision but speed is priority one. The nth root/pow algorithm i'm using converts multiple bigdecimals to doubles so I was just wondering if I should just sacrifice precision for a little more speed. I am assuming the whole neg and pos infinity is why I was encountering problems with a lot decimal places.

Comment: 1) If speed is really priority 1, then don't use BigDecimal.  Just use `double`.  (After all, you just said that a fast answer is more important than an accurate / correct one.  Actually ... what I'm saying is that you are thinking about this the wron way. )  2) Too many decimal points won't cause INF problems.  Reread the first paragraph of quoted text above.